# What is the difference between using "(use-package" and "(use-package!" with the exclamation mark by the end?

Tags: use-package

I have seen a new cool Emacs package called [gptel](https://github.com/karthink/gptel#breaking-changes). One of the ways to install it is using the `use-package` approach:

```
(use-package! gptel
 :config
 (setq! gptel-api-key "your key"))
```

However, I noticed that they use an exclamation mark `!` after `(use-package`. I can't find an explanation for the exclamation mark on the [use-package](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) documentation.

[My config file](https://github.com/pdelfino/dotfiles/blob/main/.emacs.d/init.el) heavily uses `use-package` and I have never seen such notation.

Is there a reason for the exclamation mark?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a misinterpretation on my side. `use-package!` using the exclamation mark is an adaptation for doom-emacs. More [here](https://github.com/doomemacs/doomemacs/blob/master/docs/getting_started.org#configuring-packages).

On `gptel` documentation, the README [explicitly mentioned Doom](https://github.com/karthink/gptel#doom-emacs). I was just reading fast and missed it.

On vanilla Emacs just do:

```
(use-package gptel
 :config
 (setq gptel-api-key "your-open-ai-key"))
```

Comment: FYI, you can accept your own answer.

Comment: @Drew, yeah. But, it takes awhile. Only tomorrow it will be possible.